# Write to a yaml file using jinja2 template and python

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to write data to a yaml file using a jinja2 template and python. Below is the jinja2 template

Jinja2 template:

```
name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    {{ switch_name }}:
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.30.3M
      binds:
        - {{ switch_name }}.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
```

Tried the below python code

```
import yaml
import jinja2
i = [{"switch_name": "a"}, {"switch_name": "b"}]
template_file = "eos-test-sb.clab.j2"
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="."))
template = env.get_template(template_file)
for device in i:
    result = template.render(device)
    print(result)
```

This gives me output as

```
name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    a:
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.30.3M
      binds:
        - a.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    b:
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.30.3M
      binds:
        - b.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
```

Desired Output:

```
name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    a:
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.30.3M
      binds:
        - a.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
    b:
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.30.3M
      binds:
        - b.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Before I answer... Would you able to modify the jinja template itself so it contains a `{% for ... %}` loop? I mean... can you alter the `eos-test-sb.clab.j2` file or is it some sort of "untouchable" item used everywhere in your company (for instance) that you don't wanna change?

Comment: _italic_ **bold**
`name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    {% for each in switch_name %}
        {{ each }}
    {% endfor %}
      kind: ceos
      image: ceos:4.30.3M
      binds:
        - {{ switch_name }}.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro

import yaml
import jinja2
i = [{"switch_name": "a"}, {"switch_name": "b"}]
template_file = "eos-test-sb.clab.j2"
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="."))
template = env.get_template(template_file)
for each in i:
    result = template.render(each)
    print(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" (IMHO) way of handling a for loop in the Jinja template is... in the Jinja template itself, which is very capable of using `for` loops (see [the docs](https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-2-loops-and-conditionals/)) and of accessing dictionaries (see this [other tutorial](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/iterate-dictionary-or-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template#manually-accessing-the-keys-of-each-dictionary-in-the-jinja-template))

With that in mind, modify the template to iterate over your list of devices:

Option 1)

```
name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    {% for device in devices %}
      {{ device.switch_name }}:
        kind: ceos
        image: ceos:4.30.3M
        binds:
        - {{ device.switch_name }}.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
    {%  endfor %}
```

Option 2)

```
name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    {% for device in devices %}
      {{ device['switch_name'] }}:
        kind: ceos
        image: ceos:4.30.3M
        binds:
        - {{ device['switch_name'] }}.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
    {%  endfor %}
```

Notice the only difference in those two snippets of code is just how the `device` dictionary is read: either `device.switch_name` or `device['switch_name']`. As [per the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#variables):

> You can use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable in addition to the standard Python **getitem** “subscript” syntax ([]).
>
> The following lines do the same thing:
>
> `{{ foo.bar }}`
>
> `{{ foo['bar'] }}`

Now your code just has to tell the renderer what `devices` is:

```py
import jinja2

devices = [{"switch_name": "a"}, {"switch_name": "b"}]
template_file = "eos-test-sb.clab.j2"
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="."))
template = env.get_template(template_file)

result = template.render(devices=devices)
print(result)
```

And you'll see:

```
name: eos-lab
topology:
  nodes:
    
      a:
        kind: ceos
        image: ceos:4.30.3M
        binds:
        - a.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
    
      b:
        kind: ceos
        image: ceos:4.30.3M
        binds:
        - b.txt.json:/mnt/flash/EosIntfMapping.json:ro
```